# Pre-aggregate in MongoDB or is there another solution?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a set of documents like this in a MondoDB collection:

**indicators/**

```
{
    _id: "547f04292b25e",
    year: 2012,
    concept: "A",
    countryA: "US",
    countryB: "SE",
    dimension1: "A",
    dimension2: "B",
    dimension3: "C",
    value: 200
} 
[...]
```

My front-end typically wants to display x dimensions here in a hierarchical fashion, for example:

```
dimensionA value
dimensionA countryA value
dimensionA countryA countryB value
```

I could of course do this on the frontend but the data is 10+ MB in all. Therefore it would be useful to quickly generate various aggregates (either pre or on the fly).

What would you suggest?

Comment: So there are always two countries? Could you post the data that you are actually showing on the screen based on the sample document, the hierarchy example is insufficient.

Comment: Thanks @BatScream. Well, the countries are in essence dimensions just as the other ones. What is shown on the screen is a treemap or similar: http://sushanthece.github.io/D3-Zoomable-treemap/